# Have a common webapp in a multi module Java/scala project?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I'm using SBT/scala but this question could also apply to Maven/Java projects as SBT is based on Maven structures.

I'd like to set up a multi module application that shares a common webapp deployment. How in Maven/SBT should I structure my project and at the package step have the webapp available?

structure

```
sharedlibrary/
   webapp/
module1
module2
module3
```

so when I package up module1(which depends on sharedlibrary) I'd like the webapp included in the final war file. The webapp will have code that loads up the correct Module1 Main class based on what server it's started up on. Is that possible in an easy fashion in maven/sbt?

Answer (score 1):

I not very familiar with the intricacies of sbt, but I started setting up a somewhat similar project recently.  Here's what I would try first for your situation.

1) create a "project" subdirectory on the same level as your module* folders.

2) create a new file "project/Build.scala" with the following content.  Be sure to change the `destPath` value to the directory name you need.  The paths in this example are set up to work with Google App Engine using a `war` folder within each *module*.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  lazy val copyDependencies = TaskKey[Unit]("copy-dependencies")
  def copyDepTask = copyDependencies <<= {
    (dependencyClasspath in Runtime, baseDirectory) map { (dep, bp) => 
    for (attrSrcPath <- dep) {
      val srcPath = attrSrcPath.data
      println(srcPath);
      if (!srcPath.isDirectory) {
        val destPath = bp / "war/WEB-INF/lib" / srcPath.getName
        IO.copyFile(srcPath, destPath, preserveLastModified=true)
      }
      else {
        val destPath = bp / "war/WEB-INF/classes/"
        IO.copyDirectory(srcPath, destPath, preserveLastModified=true)
      }
    }
  }

  lazy val webapp = Project("webapp", file("sharedlibrary/webapp"))
  lazy val module1 = Project("module1", file("module1"),
      settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(copyDepTask)
    ) dependsOn(webapp)
  lazy val module2 = Project("module2", file("module2"),
      settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(copyDepTask)
    ) dependsOn(webapp)
  lazy val module3 = Project("module3", file("module3"),
      settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(copyDepTask)
    ) dependsOn(webapp)
}
```

3) from within sbt, you can then enter `project module1` and `copy-dependencies`, and sbt will copy the class files from *webapp* to *module1*'s `war/WEB-INF/classes` and dependent jars to `war/WEB-INF/lib`.

For Google App Engine, I do this before running the development server or uploading the project to appspot, and it works fine, though it'd be nice to automate the process more someday.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

see SBT multi-projects:

> https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Multi-Project

and sbt-assembly plugin:

> https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly